# Python WorkSheet creation with range list

Tags: python

I want to create a spreadsheet in below format. But unable to do it, Please help.

Every worksheet should have date which start from 25th and end at 24 without Saturday and Sunday.

```
def daterange(date1, date2):
    for n in range(int ((date2 - date1).days)+1):
        yield date1 + timedelta(n)

start_dt = date(2020,9,25)
end_dt = date(2020,10,24)

weekdays = [5,6]
for dt in daterange(start_dt, end_dt):
    if dt.weekday() not in weekdays:     # to print only the weekdates
        print(dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Also want to add same date in each sheet cell with a table (unable to create a table yet).

```
import xlwt
import datetime

workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('Sheet1')

date_format = xlwt.XFStyle()
date_format.num_format_str = 'dd/mm/yyyy'

worksheet.write(0, 0, datetime.datetime.now(), date_format)

workbook.save('date_format.xls')
```

[image]

Comment: So what exactly is your question?  If this code generated an error, we need to see the full traceback message.  If it just didn't do what you expected, we need to know what it did, and what you expected.

Comment: The first script can give me the date which I expected for creating the desired sheet. Second sheet can create new sheet in a newly created workbook. But I am unable to merge them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
import xlwt
import datetime

start = datetime.date(2020, 9, 25)
end = datetime.date(2020, 10, 24)
weekend=[5, 6]

def daterange(date1, date2):
    for n in range(int((date2 - date1).days) + 1):
        yield date1 + datetime.timedelta(n)

dates = [dt for dt in daterange(start, end) if dt.weekday() not in weekend]
workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
for date in dates:
    worksheet = workbook.add_sheet(f"{date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')}") # the tab
    worksheet.write(0, 0, date.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')) # the cell
workbook.save('date_format.xls')
```

You had most of it done, all that was needed was to glue the 2 parts together.

Comment: For each data there should be a new TAB with Tab name as a date.

Comment: example image shared in the Question

Comment: Tab name format is not matching the cell.dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: in the picture you have `day-[month name abbreviation]-yyyy`, which is what this does. If you mean to have the cell value match the tab name, that can be done using a formula `fmla = xlwt.Formula('MID(CELL("Filename"),FIND("]",CELL("Filename"))+1,31)')` and then `worksheet.write(0,0,fmla)`

Comment: That's not what the picture shows, but i updated it again to use ISO format in the tab name and `day-[month abbreviation]-yyyy` in the cell

Comment: I think you are not using MS office, cause I still see "2020-09-25" as TAB Name.

Comment: i see, you needed it as `day-month-year`. ok, i added that (`date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')`)